# DOCX4j : space removed in pdf by deploying war file into tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, docx4j

I am using below code to convert docx to pdf using DOCX4j.While running this code into IDE it is working fine and space preserved after conversion. For deployment I created war and put it into tomcat server. But into test server space is not preserved into document after conversion.

pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-JAXB-Internal -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-Internal</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-JAXB-MOXy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-MOXy</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-export-fo -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

code for conversion

```
private byte[] docxToPdfBytes() {

        InputStream templateInputStream = null;
        try {
            templateInputStream = new FileInputStream(ApplicationConstants.TEMP_DOCX_PATH);
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(ApplicationConstants.TEMP_PDF_PATH);
            Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ApplicationConstants.TEMP_PDF_PATH));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.info(XrefSubscriberServiceService.class.getName() + "==> Method : docxToPdfBytes");
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally {
            if(null != templateInputStream) {
                try {
                    templateInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.info(XrefSubscriberServiceService.class.getName() + "==> Method : docxToPdfBytes");
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
    }
        
        return null;
    }
```

So can anyone have idea why this type of behaviour is happened ??

Comment: By the way, you have 3 competing docx4j-JAXB implementations there.  You should have one and only one, so delete 2 of them.

Comment: Hi @JasonPlutext , Can you please tell me reason behind that ?

Answer (score 0):

this question is resolved. Just need to correct docx styling of font in docx document.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).